# SQL Query to conditionally display values in DB2

Tags: db2

I need to conditionally display values by joining 3 different tables, below is the sample data,

```
TABLE A
LOCATION  SITE  LOCATIONID
  100      DEMO   1234
  10       DEMO   1050 
TABLE B
LOCATION   PARENT  SITE   
 100        10     DEMO   
TABLE C
LDKEY    LDTEXT    LDOWNERTABLE
1234     Hello      A
1050     Welcome    A
OR
TABLE C
LDKEY    LDTEXT    LDOWNERTABLE
1050     Welcome    A
```

When Select query is executed on Table A then it should bring output as 100 if its locationid (1234) has a record in Table C .

```
Output 1
LOCATION SITE LDTEXT
 100    DEMO  Hello
```

If there is no record corresponding to locationid(1234) in table C then it should bring in its parent's LDTEXT

```
OUTPUT 2 
LOCATION SITE  LDTEXT
 100     DEMO   Welcome
```

Below is the query that I had tried and it brought me both the records 100 and 10 ideally it should bring me only 100 with LDTEXT as HELLO

```
select * from A where (location = '100' and site = 'DEMO' 
and (locationsid in (select ldkey from C where ldownertable='A' )) or
location in ( select parent from B where location = '100' and site =   'DEMO' and 
locationsid in (select ldkey from C where ldownertable='A' )))
```

Comment: What is the query that is not working? What have you tried?

Comment: @data_henrik Thanks for your reply! I have added the query which I tried.

Comment: Take a look at the CASE statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as is. You may uncomment the commented out line to check the difference.

```
WITH 
  A (LOCATION, SITE, LOCATIONID) AS
(
VALUES
  (100, 'DEMO', 1234)
, ( 10, 'DEMO', 1050)
)
, B (LOCATION, PARENT, SITE) AS
(
VALUES
  (100, 10, 'DEMO')
)
, C (LDKEY, LDTEXT, LDOWNERTABLE) AS
(
VALUES
  (1050, 'Welcome', 'A')
--, (1234, 'Hello',   'A')
)
SELECT A.LOCATION, A.SITE, COALESCE(C1.LDTEXT, C2.LDTEXT) LDTEXT
FROM A
LEFT JOIN
(
B
JOIN A A2 ON A2.LOCATION = B.PARENT 
) ON B.LOCATION = A.LOCATION
LEFT JOIN C C1 ON C1.LDKEY = A.LOCATIONID
LEFT JOIN C C2 ON C2.LDKEY = A2.LOCATIONID
WHERE A.LOCATION = 100
;
```